# Fit image to div, with a max height of Xpx and Xvh

Tags: html, css

I have been looking to find a solution which allows me to set an image to have a max height of 85vh, but also a max-height in px (to stop an image growing larger than I want), whilst using object-fit:contain.

I have managed to get this working with the following. This is the best approach I have found, so wondering if I am missing something? Does anyone have any guidance on ways to slimline this?

```css
.spacer-outer {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
}

.spacer-outer .spacer-inner {
  display: inline-flex;
 max-height: 85vh;
}

.spacer-outer .spacer-inner .image {
 display: inline-flex;
 flex: 1;
 max-height: 750px;
}

.spacer-outer .spacer-inner img {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;    
 object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="spacer-outer">     
 <div class="spacer-inner">
  <div class="image">
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Monasterio_Khor_Virap%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-01%2C_DD_25.jpg/1920px-Monasterio_Khor_Virap%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-01%2C_DD_25.jpg" srcset="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Monasterio_Khor_Virap%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-01%2C_DD_25.jpg/1920px-Monasterio_Khor_Virap%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-01%2C_DD_25.jpg, https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Monasterio_Khor_Virap%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-01%2C_DD_25.jpg/1920px-Monasterio_Khor_Virap%2C_Armenia%2C_2016-10-01%2C_DD_25.jpg 2x" width="1920" height="982" title="Test" alt="Test">
  </div> <!-- End of .image -->
 </div> <!-- End of .spacer-inner -->
 <div class="spacer-image-caption">
  Test Caption
 </div> <!-- End of .spacer-image-caption -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best to set the max-height to vh, then override it with a media query at a pixel size where 85vh > 750px;

```
.image {
    max-height: 85vh;
}

@media (min-height: 882px) {
    .image {
        max-height: 750px;
    }
}
```

Comment: So obvious now you've said it! Thank you.